# Workflow triggering repeated e-mails if condition met

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm trying to design a workflow in SPD to send an e-mail reminder to an employee to complete a workstation assessment. I want the first e-mail to go out 35 days after their start date and then two more at 14 day intervals if they do not complete it after the first e-mail.

Here is my rather amateurish attempt at achieving this using calculated fields, which, unsurprisingly, hasn't worked. Should I be using stages or loops or something?

[image]

---

I've now split it up into stages and added some more criteria but it's not getting beyond stage 2. The 'First reminder' etc. columns are hidden choice columns set to 'No' by default and the 'Workstation Reminder 1' etc. columns are the calculated dates on which I want it to send the e-mails.

Any ideas as to why it will only send the first e-mail, please?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any checking conditions between emails.  I would put each email in a separate step, with your if statement as the condition before each one.  I would also wait until the reminder date until checking your if statements.  It would look something like this:

```
Step 1:  Wait until first reminder date
pause until Reminder 1 

Step 2:  Reminder 1
If Current Staff
And assessment complete = no
    Then Send email 1
    Then pause until Reminder 2

Step 3:  Reminder 2
If Current Staff
And assessment complete = no
    Then Send email 2
    Then pause until Reminder 3

Step 4:  etc...
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you should create a **2nd Stage** that sends the email then waits 35 days, then a **3rd Stage** that sends another email then waits 14 days. You can always set a variable that increments at the end of a stage, and in your "Transition to Stage", check the variable to see how many times the email has been sent.

```
If it's 0, go to the 2nd stage

if it's 1 or 2, go to the 3rd Stage, 

if it's 3, then do something else.
```